# List of Data as Struts Checkbox

Tags: java, jsp, dictionary, checkbox, struts

I have `Map<String,boolean>` attributes in my Struts Model Bean.
I want them to be displayed as List of Check-boxes in jsp page

So when user selects any checkbox(s), the respective attributes should be selected in action class.

How do i achieve this?

In jsp

```
<s:iterator value="myMap">
    <s:checkbox id='<s:property value="key" />' name='<s:property value="key" />' />
</siterator>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
 <s:iterator value="myMap">
        <s:checkbox name='<s:property value="key" />' value='<s:property value="value" />' />
    </siterator>
```